# Google Chart "Unable to get property 'replaceChild' of undefined or null reference" error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-app-engine, google-api, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google Chart in Internet Explorer. I'm using the Timeline chart, but whenever I hover with the mouse over a line in the chart, and then move the mouse away, it results in an error:

> Unable to get property 'replaceChild' of undefined or null reference

This is happening event when going to the official Google Charts documentation: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline
which means this is not something wrong in my code.

Anyone has an idea on how to resolve/handle this?

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  What operating system?

Comment: @asgallant: IE10 on Win8

Comment: That is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1258) with the Timeline charts and IE10.  You can visit that link and "star" the issue to get updates on a fix.

Comment: @ZigMandel, you seriously advice SaguiItay to tell "uninstall IE" to his or hers customers?

Comment: @davidconrad you missed the smiley in my post, but yea I do think it would do an inmense service to the users if they uninstalled ie. ie has done inmense damage to the web.